# Union to handle NULL values

Tags: sql, oracle, select, union

I need to write the query as below in Oracle SQL:

```
select a,b,null,null from table1      
union    
select null,null,c,d from table2    
union     
select null,null,null,null,e,f from table3
```

I am expecting output to be like this:

```
a,b,c,d,e,f
```

Edit: Sorry i had to update this question since the original question i asked was not matching with output i was expecting.

I have tables as below:

```
TABLE1
---------
 A  | B
---------
 A1 | B1
 A2 | B2
 A3 | B3


TABLE2
---------
 C  | D
---------
 C1 | D1
 C2 | D2
 C3 | D3
 C4 | D4
 C5 | D5


TABLE3
---------
 E  | F
---------
 E1 | F1
 E2 | F2
 E3 | F3
 E4 | F4
 E5 | F5
 E6 | F7
 E7 | F8
```

I do not know how to write an Oracle sql which would fetch me the below output. As shown below, I need not null values to be at the start of all output fields

```
 A        B       C       D       E        F
------- ------- ------- -------- -------- -------
 A1      B1      C1      D1       E1       F1
 A2      B2      C2      D2       E2       F2
 A3      B3      C3      D3       E3       F3
 null    null    C4      D4       E4       F4
 null    null    C5      D5       E5       F5
 null    null    null    null     E6       F7
 null    null    null    null     E7       F8
```

Comment: Show the ddl. Looks like you have to use `join` not `union`.

Comment: To use `UNION` you need to have the same number of columns selected.

Comment: Do the records from each of the tables relate to one another somehow, or is there just one per table?

Comment: the records from the tables are not related to one other. They are different tables with different columns

Answer (score 2):

`union` adds rows from different tables one **after** the other, and then removes duplicates. In order to get the output you're expecting, you should use a join.
If you any key the creates a logical relation between the tables:

```
SELECT a, b, c, d, e, f
FROM   table1
JOIN   table2 ON table1.id = table2.t1_id
JOIN   table3 ON table2.id = table3.t2_id
```

If you don't (or if each table indeed contains only one row), you could use a `cross join`:

```
SELECT     a, b, c, d, e, f
FROM       table1
CROSS JOIN table2
CROSS JOIN table3
```

Answer (score 0):

Without shared fields to perform a traditional join, you need to sort your tables properly to line up the records and adopt the row number as a key.

```
CREATE VIEW V1 (A,B,I) AS SELECT a,b,ROWNUM FROM table1 ORDER BY something 
CREATE VIEW V2 (C,D,I) AS SELECT c,d,ROWNUM FROM table2 ORDER BY something 
CREATE VIEW V3 (E,F,I) AS SELECT e,f,ROWNUM FROM table3 ORDER BY something
```

Then you can join the tables (two at a time for simplicity):

```
CREATE VIEW V1_2 (A,B,C,D,I) AS SELECT 
    v1.a,v1.b,
    v2.c,v2.d, 
    NVL(v1.i,v2.i)
FROM v1 full outer join v2 on v1.i=v2.i 

CREATE VIEW V1_2_3 (A,B,C,D,E,F,I) AS SELECT 
    v1_2.a,v1_2.b,v1_2.c,v1_2.d, 
    v3.e,v3.f,
    NVL(v1_2.i,v3.i)
FROM v1_2 full outer join v3 on v1_2.i=v3.i
```

v_1_2_3 (which doesn't strictly need column i) contains the result.